# Timer on assembly language

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

What can I use to time a loop on assembly language (like for example the clock_t on c++)?

I need to take the time the loop takes to make the sum. This is my code:

```
TITLE Summing an Array               (SumArray.asm)

; This program sums an array of words.

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
intarray DWORD 10000h,20000h,30000h,40000h, 50000h, 60000h, 70000h

.code
main PROC

mov  edi,OFFSET intarray ; 1: EDI = address of intarray
mov  ecx,LENGTHOF intarray ; 2: initialize loop counter
mov  eax,0 ; 3: sum = 0
L1: ; 4: mark beginning of loop
add  eax,[edi] ; 5: add an integer
add  edi,TYPE intarray ; 6: point to next element

call dumpRegs

loop L1 ; 7: repeat until ECX = 0



exit

main ENDP
END main
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rdtsc` to get the value of the [time stamp counter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter) before and after the code you're interested in timing and subtract the “before” value from the “after” value.